# Showing the interaction between 2 actors on 1 sequence diagram

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm struggling to see how I can show this on a sequence diagram.

The scenario is, I have to show how a system decides which reservation (for a library book) should be processed first.

There are 2 possible actors, a normal member and a loyal member.

Loyal members have higher priority than a normal member so whenever they reserve a book they go ahead of the queue in front of all normal members. If they have the same member type then it's whoever reserved the book initially/earlier that has higher priority.

Any hints or examples would be very helpful for me.

I thought of using an ALT frame? Or should I just show it in 2 different sequence diagrams one for each actor?

Comment: A sequence diagram may not be the right choice here if you're trying to visualize the algorithm by which the system decides which reservation to choose. For that I'd rather have an activity diagram. Sequence diagrams are used to visualize communication *between* several (sub-)systems as well as its timing and not for modeling system-internal behaviour. Therefore the sequence diagram would be quite trivial here, because you'd only have two actors sending requests to the library system and getting one response each, telling whether or not the reservation was successful...

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasHeinrich how would an activity diagram solve the problem of different actions depending on the action hierarchy? you would still need either two diagrams or an `instanceof` choice node, which IMHO is bad modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot show this in one sequence diagram. Use two diagrams to show the interaction, one using the normal member and one using the loyal member. In the diagram of the loyal member show that the member is skipped to the front of the line when he reserves a book.